# custom filtering in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I am trying to implement custom filtering in my code and went through the documentation. But I couldnt understand the following snippets from the docs.

```
class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'last_login']

# or

class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = {
            'username': ['exact', 'contains'],
            'last_login': ['exact', 'year__gt'],
        }
```

The doc says we can use either one the first or second one but what is the exact difference?? What is the meaning of contains and year_gt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a link in the docs there for the [django lookups docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/lookups/#module-django.db.models.lookups) also, and what you'll find with this is that you can make searching/filtering more efficient by using that second option.

The first option in the docs, where `fields` is just a list will do an exact match query against each of the fields you list.

In the second option, hat the filters library will do with the `fields` dictionary is it'll use "double underscore" notation to create lookups of;

- `username__exact`
- `username__contains`
- `last_login__exact`
- `last_login__year__gt`

You can use the double underscore to access an attribute of something, or the lookup type. So on `last_login` for that final example above, it'll take the year of the `last_login` value and for that year, the lookup type is greater than (`gt`).

There are lots of these lookup values that can be really helpful to learn. For example, `contains` is case sensitive but you can use `icontains` for a case insensitive match. There's also `lt` for less than, or `lte`/`gte` for less/greater than or equal. Check out the available lookups [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups).

Comment: Thanks, for the beautiful explanation @markwalker. so for the second way i have to use `/api/person?username__contains` or `/api/person?username__exact` not only username like in the first case, right?

Comment: @Django-Rocks I don't think you really need to do anything besides define that `fields` attribute how best suits you. Those paths would be correct, but filters should take care of things so you don't have to. What I'd say is that option 2 is the best approach, it's efficient and you can control the queries more.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but when i call the api /api/person?username__exact i have to pass query paramter like this or only /api/person?username in second way??? thats my confusion

Comment: Ah I think I understand now. If you setup with option 2, then you'd query the server with `/api/person?username__exact=mark` for example, then `mark` gets fed into that `FilterSet` class using the fields dictionary to do an exact match on `username`. Does that answer that for you?

Comment: ok mark thanks, one last question. If I have to query for multiple names like username__contains=max,mark,john etc how can I do that with just filterset class??

Comment: You'd likely use the `in` lookup there. You can use a list with that, so `/api/person?username__in=mark,ben,bob,steve`. You can also use these lookups when viewing the django admin if you want to see how things might work before adding them to your api.

Comment: so the __in keyword will split the name and take it??

Comment: Yeah, the specifics of that lookup are here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#in

Comment: I think I have to use it like this then? `fields = ['username__in', 'last_login__in']` and query like api/person?username__in=mark,max,jon ..is it correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239730/discussion-between-markwalker-and-django-rocks).

Answer (score 4):

**What is the exact difference ?**

With `fields = ['username', 'last_login']`, the generated filters are :

`qs.filter(username='some_value')` and `qs.filter(last_login=some_date_value)`

With

```
fields = {
        'username': ['exact', 'contains'],
        'last_login': ['exact', 'year__gt'],
    }
```

the generated filters are :

`qs.filter(username='some_value')`, `qs.filter(username__contains='some_value')` for the `username` field.

`qs.filter(last_login=some_date_value)`, `qs.filter(last_login__year__gt=some_year_value)` for the `last_login` field.

So we can see at first time that the second produce 2 filters options for each field, and the first produce only one filter option (`exact match`) for the given value.

**What is the meaning of contains and year__gt ?**

`contains` is used to filter by a value that can be found inside a field.
ex: `dj` is in `django`.

`year__gt` in other hand is only for date field. When you have a date field like `created`, Django let you filter by the `year`, `month`, `day` by just do : `.filter(created__year=2021, created__month=12)`. And more possibility by `.filter(created__year__gt=2020)` that means **the year of created field > 2020**. It can be applied to `month__gt` (month > 11), `day__lt` (day < 25).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but when i call the api `/api/person?username__exact` i have to pass query paramter like this or only `/api/person?username` in second way??? thats my confusion

Comment: `/api/person?username__exact` and `/api/person?username` are the same because the `exact` option is the default behavior. Now for `contains` you need something like `/api/person?username__contains=some_value`.